Are a member's questions (and their answers) deleted when he/she removes himself from the group?
I noticed that a member's upvotes/downvotes are deleted when the member removes themselves from the group. Is it the case that the member's questions (and their answers) are also deleted?
If so, I would hope this policy can change, because it results in the deletion of much good work done by those who answered the former member's questions.

No, their posts are not removed.

Indeed, it's quite the opposite - if a departing member deletes or defaces significant quantities of their own content then Moderators will intervene to rescue the content, even if the user is no longer part of the community.

thank you both for your help.

It is actually illegal to 'destroy content' under the copyright imposed. The names of deleted accounts revert to 'user xxxxxxx' and become anonymous. Content remains. But their votes are removed from the system and one may lose hundreds of rep points when such users delete their accounts.
